# Performance when using Redis as query results storage for certain repetitive Neo4j queries

Tags: express, neo4j, redis

I am teaching myself Neo4j & Redis and work on a app to make use of both. The data domain let's assume is publications (Imaginary domain, this is not a real life project) with following structures:

Label > Publication Node - Role {title, date} 
Label > Publication Source - Role {source_name, url, id} i.e. PubMed, Scopus, etc. 
Label > Author - Role {firstname, lastname, dob, email, etc.} 
 
Label > Journal - Role {journal_name, etc.} i.e. Science, Nature

A publication is composed of title, list of authors, the journal, page numbers, doi id, and other relevant properties.

Let's assume I have a 1000 publication nodes, 5000 Author nodes, 7 Sources and 6 Journals. The data is connected with each other using relationships.

The app would provide a search screen with controls to allow searching of publications based on certain criteria. Every time the search screen is requested, the APP should return latest counts of publications as per bits (i.e. sources, years, A-Z author names, etc.).

These latest counts would give the person searching an idea of how many publications are there. See the screen mock for example (numbers in bracket show real count of nodes to which there are incoming relationships from publication nodes).

[image]

Each of those counts (i.e. Pubmed (15), Scopus (10), Immunology (95)) are results of cypher queries against the Neo4j that counts the number of incoming relationships to those Labels (assume there is like 10 cyphers queries to be run to get those counts).

If 100 users request the search screen, there will be 100 requests * 10 cyphers resulting in 1000 cypher queries fetching most of the time same values that sometimes change.

My current solution >

1) On Express initialization, run those cypher queries that retrieve counts and store them as hashes in Redis.

2) For every request asking for Search screen, HGETALL for each hash and return its value which is nothing but count.

3) Every time a new publication is added, increment the count of those relevant hashes by 1

4) Every time a publication is deleted, Query Neo4j and re-initialize the Redis (rather than searching the specific hashes and decrementing them - Need advise, whether I use Exists for hash and then HEXISTS for field of hash and then decrement or simply re-initialize the redis? Update and deletion are rare actions i.e. 22% of time).

5) Every time a publication is updated, Query neo4j and re-initialize the Redis (rather than figuring out which relationships were dropped and which hashes to be decremented and which ones to be incremented - I find reinitialization quicker? What is your advise?)

6) When searching it is tricky to decide which node to start from. Let's assume the user selects the following options during search

- CrossRef (95) as source AND
- Science (10) as journal  AND
- 2014 (200) as year  AND
- A (66) as author start name  AND

I guess from Neo4j perspective, the node (x) with least number of incoming relationship can be a good starting point because, naturally majority of publications that do not have relationship to node x will be ignored. If I start the query from node "Science" I will have 10 candidate publication nodes to check remainder of the search conditions but, if I start with year I have 200 candidate publication nodes to apply further search criteria to. if this is true, then rather than hitting another 10 cypher queries to figure out the node with least incoming relationships, I could refer to Redis for latest count figures and then build my Cypher query. What is your advise?

If the above idea of starting search from node with least incoming relationship is correct, then when the search fires the search request, I could SORT redis values for hashes and construct a cypher query with from the Node with minimum count, followed by the next minimum count and so on.

I am new to Redis & Neo4j and its applications, please advise, if you think this is not going to work out in real life with some explanations and suggestions to which other solutions should be considered.

Thanks a million for reading this big questions, I tried to be descriptive, that probably indicate the fact that I myself am confused a bit.

Comment: You can also optimize your cypher queries by using `MATCH (n:Label) WHERE ... RETURN n, size( (n)-[:REL1]->()) as count, ...`

Comment: Yeah, there shouldn't be a need for hundreds/thousands of queries.  I suspect you could do it in no more than a few (and even maybe one with Michael's suggestion, that's a neat use of size(MATCH PATTERN) in a `RETURN`).  If you can provide an example domain/query probably we could help with the Cypher

Comment: You're also welcome to ask in a channel in the slack group for some real-time help: http://neo4j.com/blog/public-neo4j-users-slack-group/